# Overriding the default storyboard view controller from the app delegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

With IB storyboards there is always a default view controller selected, which is the controller that will be presented when the app starts.

Is there any way to override this in code? For example, my app delegate logic might need to send the user elsewhere. Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put all of the following on the default controller.

```
- (void)gotoScreen:(NSString *)theScreen
{
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIViewController *screen = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:theScreen];
    [app.window setRootViewController:screen];
}
```

And then where the logic happens I'll call the following as needed.

```
if(myBool == YES) {
    [self gotoScreen:@"theIdentifier"];
}
```